# Which library is the pr_DB object defined in?

Tags: r

I am completely new to R.
I am trying to use the `dist` object with a custom function based on the specification [here](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/proxy/html/dist.html), but I was unable to pass the custom function directly by name, so I tried to add it using the registry described [here](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/proxy/html/registry.html), but it appears that I am missing a library. 
However, I'm not sure which library I need and cannot find a reference to find the name of the library.

Here's a code sample that I'm trying to run:

```
library(cluster)

myfun <- function(x,y) {
  numDiffs <- 0;
  for (i in x) {
    if (x[i] != y[i])
       numDiffs <- numDiffs + 1;
  }
  return(numDiffs);
}
summary(pr_DB)

pr_DB$set_entry(FUN = myfun, names = c("myfun", "vectorham"))
pr_DB$get_entry("MYFUN")
```

Here's the error:

```
Error in summary(pr_DB) : object 'pr_DB' not found
Execution halted
```

Comment: Do you call `library(proxy)`?

Comment: Not currently, trying that now.

Comment: I guess I need to install proxy since I got an error about it missing.

Comment: `require(sos); ???pr_DB` (yes, 3 question marks).

Comment: @F.k thanks for the reminder that the 'sos::findFn' function has a shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn the conventions used by R help pages.  That "{proxy}" at the top of the page you linked to is really the answer to your question. The convention for the help page construction is "topic {package_name}".